# Docker for NodeJS express and Python

Tags: python, node.js, docker

I would like to run an express server that can trigger NodeJS code as well as spawn Python processes.

How would I configure the Dockerfile? 
Would I for example use Ubuntu, Node or Python as my base image?

Pseudocode of Dockerfile:

```
FROM ???:???-alpine

RUN npm install 
RUN install python?
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "index" ]
```

Pseudocode of running web server:

```
www.some-url.com/jobs/my-node-js-route
=> express route that runs a node function     

www.some-url.com/jobs/my-python-route
=> express route that spawns a python process
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the below image and it worked fine when I want to work both on node and python together.

```
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:latest
```